# MySQL query to Hibernate Query

Tags: database, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

Can anyone give me the equivalent Hibernate query for the MySQL query given below. I am not trying it from past few day but no success.

This is MySql query

```
  SELECT * FROM product WHERE category_id IN (SELECT id FROM  category WHERE parent_category_id IN (SELECT id FROM category WHERE parent_category_id=53));
```

The Hibernate query which i had written is.

```
public List<Product> findBy2ndLevel(String categoryName) {

    Query query = null;
    StringBuilder hql = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        hql.append("from Product product where product.category.id in");
        hql.append("(select id from Category category where category.parentCategory.id in");
        hql.append("(select id from Category category where category.parentCategory.id=:category_id))");
        query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql.toString());
        query.setParameter("category_id",Integer.parseInt(categoryName));
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return  query.list();
}
```

It is not working though. Give anyone correct or give me the equivalent HQ.

Comment: Read the manual about HQL. You have many things wrong. Hibernate always uses entity names and their field/property names. Never tables and column names.

Comment: @JBNizet: I had made the modification

Comment: You are basically writing an SQL-query, and trying to pass it off at HQL. That won't work. You could run a pure SQL query through Hibernate, but then you would have to map the result yourself. Post the code for the entities in question (you only need to include the properties used in the query.)

Comment: `select *` is wrong. You probably want `select product`. Read the documentation. There's no way you have read it and actually tried something in 6 minutes. Also, read your own code. You're passing a parameter "org_id" that doesn't even exist in the query. And finally, define precisely what "it is not working" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the entity Product has 1 category and a variable for this (called `category`), and that a category has 1 parent category and a variable for this (called `parent`).

But, something like:

```
select p
from Product p join p.category c join c.parent pc
where pc.id = :categoryId
```

Furthermore, I don't really get your variable use, you link the id of category with `categoryName`, and include a variable `orgaId` which is never really used for anything.. Also, your code will produce a `NullPointerException` if the creation of the query fails.